# Use github token during cicd in bitrise to access npm.pkg.github.com

Tags: yaml, continuous-integration, devops, continuous-deployment, bitrise

I am quite new in building cicd and with bitrise. Currently I am trying to create a cicd for hybrid mobile app which is using react native. I have almost completed it but having an error when running yarn install during cicd. The error is

> error An unexpected error occurred:
> "https://npm.pkg.github.com/download/@someorg/abc-app/1.2.28/f479287e129b6ce227c1c1ecda507f3ecf25a9bcac024b327f2865c87a14df73: Request failed "401 Unauthorized"".

This error is due to .npmrc file in the root of my code repo, the content inside .npmrc is

```
@someorg=https://npm.pkg.github.com/
always-auth=true
```

Now my question is how can I tell bitrise cicd to use my github token when downloading from npm.pkg.github.com. I have create a secrect in bitrise with the value of my github token but where can I use that in bitrise.yml to resolve this issue. Below is the bitrise.yml file. Thanks

---

```
format_version: '11'
default_step_lib_source: https://github.com/bitrise-io/bitrise-steplib.git
project_type: react-native
workflows:
  deploy:
    description: |
      Tests, builds and deploys the app using *Deploy to bitrise.io* Step.

      Next steps:
      - Set up an [Apple service with API key]
      - Check out [Getting started with React Native apps]
    steps:
    - activate-ssh-key@4: {}
    - git-clone@6: {}
    - yarn@0:
        inputs:
        - workdir: "$WORKDIR"
        - command: install
    - yarn@0:
        inputs:
        - workdir: "$WORKDIR"
        - command: test
    - install-missing-android-tools@3:
        inputs:
        - gradlew_path: "$PROJECT_LOCATION/gradlew"
    - android-build@1:
        inputs:
        - project_location: "$PROJECT_LOCATION"
        - module: "$MODULE"
        - variant: "$VARIANT"
    - cocoapods-install@2: {}
    - xcode-archive@4:
        inputs:
        - project_path: "$BITRISE_PROJECT_PATH"
        - scheme: "$BITRISE_SCHEME"
        - distribution_method: "$BITRISE_DISTRIBUTION_METHOD"
        - configuration: Release
        - automatic_code_signing: api-key
    - deploy-to-bitrise-io@2: {}
  primary:
    description: |
      Runs tests.

      Next steps:
      - Check out [Getting started with React Native apps].
    steps:
    - activate-ssh-key@4: {}
    - authenticate-with-github-oauth@0:
        inputs:
        - access_token: "$pstoken"
        - username: "$gituser"
    - git-clone@6: {}
    - yarn@0:
        inputs:
        - workdir: "$WORKDIR"
        - command: install
    - yarn@0:
        inputs:
        - workdir: "$WORKDIR"
        - command: test
    - deploy-to-bitrise-io@2: {}
meta:
  bitrise.io:
    stack: osx-xcode-13.2.x
    machine_type_id: g2.4core
app:
  envs:
  - opts:
      is_expand: false
    WORKDIR: "."
  - opts:
      is_expand: false
    PROJECT_LOCATION: android
  - opts:
      is_expand: false
    MODULE: app
  - opts:
      is_expand: false
    VARIANT: Debug
  - opts:
      is_expand: false
    BITRISE_PROJECT_PATH: ios/some_mobile.xcworkspace
  - opts:
      is_expand: false
    BITRISE_SCHEME: some_mobile
  - opts:
      is_expand: false
    BITRISE_DISTRIBUTION_METHOD: ad-hoc
```